# Add textField programmatically and read from it in another method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my viewDidLoad i am creating a textField like below:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f,
                                                                       6.0f,
                                                                       toolBar.bounds.size.width - 20.0f - 68.0f,
                                                                       30.0f)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[toolBar addSubview:textField];
```

But i need to read text from the textField from a IBAction method..

How would i access the text within textField from that IBAction?

Answer (score 3):

Keep a reference to your UITextField object by adding an ivar in the interface :

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
UITextField *textField;
}
```

and add your method in the .m file:

```
- (IBAction)readTextField: (id)sender
{
NSLog(@"%@", textfield.text);
}
```

Comment: Ohh i had missed the reference in the interface - thank you lots ill accept asap! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Keep a reference to your UITextField object by adding an ivar in the interface or create a property of your textField.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
   UITextField *textField;
}
```

or create a property

```
@property(nonatomic, retian) UITextField *textField;
```

and synthesize it

```
@synthesize textField;

- (IBAction)GetTextFiledValue: (id)sender
  {
      NSLog(@"Your TextField value is : %@", [textfield text]);
  }
```

In the both case it'll work, but the main thing is that make you textField global so that it could be accessable from any method.